# Remove duplicate values in a list

Tags: soql, map, list, record, set

Hello Im Trying to remove duplicate values in this table
[image]

The specific field is `Sold_to_Broker_1_Commission_Rate_c`, now my method is only returning the list with others parameters (more development), the thing is that I'm trying remove values with the same value in the field mentioned, I tried with some Maps, Set but I can't.
Also once I get the Set/Map I try to convert to list

```apex
Map<String, SoldToBrokers__c> mapSObj = new Map<String, SoldToBrokers__c>();
            
//Current query working
List<SoldToBrokers__c> listBr = [SELECT Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c, Sold_to_Broker_1_Commission_Rate__c, LastModifiedDate
                                 FROM SoldToBrokers__c 
                                WHERE Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c =: brokerDesc ];
for(SoldToBrokers__c sold : listBr){
    if(!mapSObj.containsKey(sold.Sold_to_Broker_1_Commission_Rate__c)){
        mapSObj.put(sold.Sold_to_Broker_1_Commission_Rate__c, sold);
    }
}
System.debug('Maps:' +  mapSObj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The code you have right now should work

...*assuming that `Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c` only contains a single value*.

Adjusting your code so that anyone can run it via anonymous apex

```java
Map<String, Account> mapSObj = new Map<String, Account>();

//Current query working
List<Account> listBr = new List<Account>{
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555555', Description = 'First'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555555', Description = 'Second'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555557', Description = 'First'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555555', Description = 'Third'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555556', Description = 'First'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555557', Description = 'Second'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555555', Description = 'Fourth'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555556', Description = 'Second'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555557', Description = 'Third')
};

for(Account sold : listBr){
    if(!mapSObj.containsKey(sold.Fax)){
        mapSObj.put(sold.Fax, sold);
    }
}
System.debug('Maps:' +  mapSObj);
```

I get the result

```
Maps:{
    +15555555555=Account:{Name=a, Fax=+15555555555, Description=First},
    +15555555556=Account:{Name=a, Fax=+15555555556, Description=First},
    +15555555557=Account:{Name=a, Fax=+15555555557, Description=First}
}
```

There's only one copy of each Fax number, and it always stores the first instance. Turning that into a `List` is then just simply `mapSObj.values()`. `values()` always gives you a list of the value type, so a `List<Account>` for my example, and a `List<SoldToBrokers__c>` in your case.

#### If you are dealing with more than one value in `Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c`,

then you need to change how you're detecting "duplicates". Two records would only be duplicates if both `Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c` and `Sold_to_Broker_1_Commission_Rate__c` are the same between them.

You might create a formula field to concatenate the two fields together so that you have a single field that acts as a "composite key".

My preferred approach to this problem though would be to use an SObject as the key for a Map.

```java
Map<Account, Account> mapSObj = new Map<Account, Account>();

//Current query working
List<Account> listBr = new List<Account>{
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555555', Description = 'First'),
    new Account(Name = 'b', Fax = '+15555555555', Description = 'Second'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555557', Description = 'First'),
    new Account(Name = 'b', Fax = '+15555555555', Description = 'Third'),
    new Account(Name = 'b', Fax = '+15555555556', Description = 'First'),
    new Account(Name = 'b', Fax = '+15555555557', Description = 'Second'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555555', Description = 'Fourth'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555556', Description = 'Second'),
    new Account(Name = 'a', Fax = '+15555555557', Description = 'Third')
};

for(Account sold : listBr){
    // Using the SObject constructor and specifying name-value pairs
    //   is easy to read, and easy to modify (adding or removing fields)
    Account sobjKey = new Account(Name = sold.Name, Fax = sold.Fax);

    // Unless you're specifically looking for the first instance of a duplicated
    //   piece of data, you don't need to check if the map contains the key already.
    // Using .put() with an existing key simply overwrites the value stored by
    //   the map

    // The big thing you need to be wary of when using SObjects (or any other mutable
    //   object) as a Map key is that once you .put() an object instance into
    //   the map as a key, YOU MUST NOT MODIFY THAT OBJECT INSTANCE.
    // If you do, then you can make it impossible to retrieve data from your map
    // Account sobjKey = new Account(...); is fine because `sobjKey` is basically
    //   being "redeclared" in every iteration of the loop.
    // sobjKey should be declared _inside of the loop_ for safety
    // sobjKey should be set to a new object instance every time
    // using dot notation (e.g. sobjKey.Name = 'new name';) after putting
    //   a key into a map is dangerous because _that also affects the
    //   data in the key itself_
    mapSObj.put(sobjKey, sold);

}
System.debug('Maps:' +  mapSObj);
```

This gives me the result

```
Maps:{
    Account:{Name=a, Fax=+15555555555}=Account:{Name=a, Fax=+15555555555, Description=Fourth}, 
    Account:{Name=a, Fax=+15555555556}=Account:{Name=a, Fax=+15555555556, Description=Second}, 
    Account:{Name=a, Fax=+15555555557}=Account:{Name=a, Fax=+15555555557, Description=Third}, 
    Account:{Name=b, Fax=+15555555555}=Account:{Name=b, Fax=+15555555555, Description=Third}, 
    Account:{Name=b, Fax=+15555555556}=Account:{Name=b, Fax=+15555555556, Description=First}, 
    Account:{Name=b, Fax=+15555555557}=Account:{Name=b, Fax=+15555555557, Description=Second}
}
```

#### You may be able to do this with just a query

If you don't particularly care about losing data granularity, you could also accomplish this with the query alone by using `GROUP BY` (which results in a `List<AggregateResult>` rather than a `List<SoldToBrokers__c>`)

```java
// When using GROUP BY, every field in the SELECT needs to either appear in
//   the GROUP BY (you can group by multiple fields), or have an aggregate
//   function (MIN(), MAX(), AVG(), COUNT(), COUNT_DISTINCT(), SUM()) applied to it.
// Be aware that COUNT_DISTINCT() is not what you want to use here
List<AggregateResult> listBr = [
    SELECT Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c, Sold_to_Broker_1_Commission_Rate__c, MIN(LastModifiedDate)
    FROM SoldToBrokers__c 
    WHERE Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c = :brokerDesc
    GROUP BY Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c, Sold_to_Broker_1_Commission_Rate__c
];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this to remove duplicates

```apex
Set<SoldToBrokers__c> setBr = new Set<SoldToBrokers__c>([SELECT Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c, Sold_to_Broker_1_Commission_Rate__c, LastModifiedDate FROM SoldToBrokers__c WHERE Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c =: brokerDesc ]);
List<SoldToBrokers__c> listBr = new List<SoldToBrokers__c>();
listBr.addAll(setBr);
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thank you for your contribution. Here on SFSE the *why* (explanation) is often as or more important than the *how* (code) in an answer - especially since it can help future searchers/readers. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/384614/edit) your answer to explain - even briefly (but enough to understand) - why the code you posted should remove duplicates.

Comment: I've downvoted this because the inclusion of `LastModifiedDate` in the query all but guarantees that simply putting the result of the query into a Set will not remove duplicates in this case. This approach works well when you're dealing with primitive types. When you use more complex types like an SObject, however, you need to be mindful about what data is included.